# Restricting access for static class

Tags: c#, .net

As a part of learning process, I am writing simple IM app, using Remoting in .NET. As of now it is simple console app and it works as i expect. Thinking about next features/functionalities, I've stuck in a situation represented by the code below:

```
public static class UserManager {
  public static started { get; private set; }
  private static List<User> users;
  static UserManager() {
    users = List<User>();
    started = true;
  }
  public static addUser(int _userID) {}
  public static activateUser(int _userID) {
    foreach (User u in users) {
      if (u.userID == _userID) {
        u.setActive();
        break;
      }
    }
  }
}

class User {
  public int userID { get; private set; }
  public bool active { get; private set; }
  public User(int _userID) {
    userID = _userID;
  }
  public void setActive() {
    // only UserManager should be allowed to modify user state
  }
}
```

I want to make only UserManager static class be allowed to modify states of it's users list. I was thinking about "friend" clause but as I understand, there is no such construct in C#. Would it be enough just checking (inside User class methods), if calling "object" is of class UserManager?

I would appreciate any input/advice, including those saying "don't do that as You try to do, better make it using.."

PS. Didn't know which Title should i choose, feel free (more experienced programmers/so users) to change it if ther is more accurate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put the `UserManager` and `User` classes in their own assembly and mark parts of the API as `internal` (which is the equivalent of VB's `Friend`).  This enables you to restrict access from outside that assembly.

Another way to restrict access is by doing role based security. .NET has the [PrincipalPermissionAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.permissions.principalpermissionattribute.aspx) for this:

```
public static class UserManager 
{
    [PrincipalPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, 
        Role = "Administrators")]
    public static void AddUser(int userId) { }
}
```

Note that this will only work when you know the role of the user, but it is especially useful in scenario's such as web sites (ASP.NET WebForms / MVC) and web services (WCF) were users normally log on.

Comment: I had read about "internal solution" before but I wanted to know other's opinions on the problem. I don't want to mess with user's roles, so I'll stick to "internal solution". Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 0):

The only options I can think of for really restricting access to the members of `User` to `UserManager` at compile time are:

- Put the two of them in their own assembly, and make the members internal
- Make `UserManager` a nested class within `User` and make the members private

If you just make the members internal, it will limit access to the assembly anyway - can you not make the assembly sufficiently small that you can trust code written within that assembly?

(Just as a friendly bit of advice, I suggest you look up the Microsoft .NET naming conventions - it'll make your code look much more like idiomatic C#.)

Comment: I will surely read these naming conventions, thank You for pointing it out. Is it possible to generate many dll's from single project? I mean "one dll for these two class files, another one for some other classes"? Or should I create another project in the VS solution?

Comment: @dygi: In normal situations 1 dll equals 1 VS project. It's not advisable to create many small projects with just a few types. This will become unmanageable pretty soon. Best practice is to group types by layer (i.e. presentation layer, business layer, data layer, etc).